# Marking a specific point on a graph in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, graph, plot, points

I guess this is a very basic question.

I have a graph which I created in MATLAB. This is a graph of Power (y-axis) versus Frequency (x-axis).

The range of my x-axis is from 0 to 1000. Now here is my problem. I want to draw a line from specific points on the x-axis to the graph. For example, for points 40, 400, 950.

By using  `set(gca, 'XTick', [40 400 950]);` I am able to mark these particular points. But I want to make it more visible by drawing straight vertical lines from these points.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers. On a similar note, what do you think would be the best way to color particular areas in the graph? For example if I want to color the part of the graph from x = 40 to x = 400 red and the region x = 400 to x = 950 blue, how do you think I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `plot` with endpoints with the same `x` value and different `y` values. (and don't forget to use [myaa](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20979) to beautify the output).

```
x = 0:0.1:2*pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y);
hold on;
plot([0.6 0.6], [-1 1], 'Color', [0.7 0.7 0.7], 'LineWidth', 2);
plot([3.6 3.6], [-1 1], 'Color', [0.7 0.7 0.7], 'LineWidth', 2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you do this often I would recommend you a great submission from the FileExchange:

[hline and vline](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/1039)

Just do:

```
vline([40 400 950])
```

Read the function documentation, if you want the line to have different properties than default.

Answer (score 0):

I typically do this using something like this (is `powers` is a row vector).

```
powers = randn(1,1000)+40;
plot([1;1]*[40 400 950], [[0 0 0]; [powers([40 400 950])]],'k-')
```